# VPN entries no longer appearing in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, 15.10

I have a range of VPNs configured and working in 15.04, and accessible from the network icon in the toolbar (network -> VPN Connections).

I've updated to 15.10 and that list is now empty.  VPN connections just now gives me 'Configure VPN' or (disabled) 'Disconnect VPN'.

When I select 'Configure VPN', then I can get the 'Network Connections' window up, and in the VPN section *it has all of my VPN connections*.  I can individually edit the VPN settings, but I am never given the option of being able to actually *connect* to a VPN.

Has something changed in the way we access VPN connections?

Comment: I filed this bug for the same problem.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openconnect/+bug/1502847

Comment: @LuisAlves - This doesn't appear to be the same problem as the issue you posted.